# Using mechanize with python, logging in to the wsj.com

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

It feels like I have tried everything so I'm hoping someone out there will be able to help. I am trying to automate the log-in to the wall street journal (wsj.com). I have tried my code on various other sites and it worked fine. However it does not seem to be logging me in to the wsj. Below is my code, I would deeply appreciate any light someone could shed as to why it isn't working and how to fix it. I assume it has something to do with the submit control being set to disabled and readonly. But I could not get that control to successfully change.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cookielib
import urllib
import requests
import mechanize

# Log-in to wsj.com
cj = mechanize.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj) 

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://id.wsj.com/access/pages/wsj/us/login_standalone.html?mg=id-wsj')

# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['username'] = '****'
br.form['password'] = '****' 

# Login
br.submit()
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. What do you get when you run this?

Comment: I am checking the page title as a reference. When on the log in page, page title is log in. When on the main website page after logging in, the title is something else. I keep getting Log In as the page title. But I'm not getting any errors. Maybe I am doing something wrong when testing?